# AttributeError: module 'urllib3.request' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'

Tags: python, urllib

Не работает мой код:

```
import urllib3.request
urllib3.request.urlretrieve('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/list-3.svg?v=323a95564232.png', 'my_image.jpg')
```

Ошибка: AttributeError: module 'urllib3.request' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'

Comment: С urllib все работает. Обязательна urllib3?

Comment: Ну да, в urllib3 такой функции никогда и не существовало

Comment: Я уже пытался с urllib, с urllib.requsts, urllib3 и urllib3.requests. У всех одна и та же ошибка.